# How can I change CSS display none or block property using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I change CSS display none or block property using jQuery?

Answer (score 1153, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use `show` and `hide`:

```
$('#id').hide();
$('#id').show();
```

An alternate way is to use the jQuery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) method:

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");
$("#id").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: @GenericTypeTea: `#id` used for ids what about if I want to use `class`?

Comment: `$(".class").css("display", "none");`

Comment: I tried using `$('#id').css('display', 'none');`, but it did not work. However, using `$('#id').css('color', 'red');` does work. I am not sure why, though. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @David I tried the exact code     $('#id').css('display', 'none'); and it did worked for me, I wonder why it did'nt worked for you.

Comment: It is also worth to include difference between $('#id').hide() and $("#id").css("display", "none") in this answer.

Comment: If you need remove css in class, you need use .removeClass ex. $(".img-responsive").removeClass("display");

Comment: i had the same problem. display:block is worked but i want to set display:normal its not happening here.

can someone help me ?.

Comment: There is a difference between two, where former function hides the text only and doesn't free up a space occupied by an element whereas latter hide the content and free up the space occupied by cocern element

Answer (score 123):

There are several ways to accomplish this, each with its own intended purpose.

---

**1**.) To use *inline* while simply assigning an element a list of things to do

```
$('#ele_id').css('display', 'block').animate(....
$('#ele_id').css('display', 'none').animate(....
```

---

**2**.) To use while setting multiple CSS properties

```
$('#ele_id').css({
    display: 'none'
    height: 100px,
    width: 100px
});
$('#ele_id').css({
    display: 'block'
    height: 100px,
    width: 100px
});
```

---

**3**.) To dynamically call on command

```
$('#ele_id').show();
$('#ele_id').hide();
```

---

**4**.) To dynamically toggle between block and none, if it's a div

- *some elements are displayed as inline, inline-block, or table, depending on the [Ta](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/)[g N](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3478151/Web-Developer-Class-Learn-the-Basic-HTML-Tags.htm)[ame](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)*

> $('#ele_id').toggle();

Answer (score 31):

If the display of the div is block by default, you can just use `.show()` and `.hide()`, or even simpler, `.toggle()` to toggle between visibility.

Comment: True, it will set display to whatever it was initially, which could be block or something different.

Answer (score 11):

For hide:

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");
```

For show:

```
$("#id").css("display", "");
```

Answer (score 10):

In javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

and in jquery:

```
$("#myDIV").css({display: "none"});
$("#myDIV").css({display: "block"});
```

---

and you can use:

```
$('#myDIV').hide();
$('#myDIV').show();
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple way:

```
function displayChange(){
$(content_id).click(function(){
  $(elem_id).toggle();}

)}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 7):

Other way to do it using jQuery CSS method:

```
$("#id").css({display: "none"});
$("#id").css({display: "block"});
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to hide and show an element, depending on whether it is already visible or not, you can use 
toggle instead of `.hide()` and `.show()`

```
$('elem').toggle();
```

Answer (score 4):

$("#id").css("display", "none");

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  $("#id").css("display", "none");
}, 2000)
$("#id2").css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='id'>Hello World!</div>
<div id='id2'>Hello World 2!</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.displayChange = function(fn){
        $this = $(this);
        var state = {};
        state.old = $this.css('display');
        var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
            if( $this.css('display') != state.old ){
                state.change = $this.css('display');
                fn(state);
                state.old = $this.css('display');
            }
        }, 100);        
    }

    $(function(){
        var tag = $('#content');
        tag.displayChange(function(obj){
            console.log(obj);
        });  
    })   
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 2):

.hide() does not work in Chrome for me.

This works for hiding:

```
var pctDOM = jQuery("#vr-preview-progress-content")[0];
pctDOM.hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#id").(":display").val("block");
```

Or:

```
$("#id").(":display").val("none");
```

Comment: i have problem its not working for me :(.
`<style>
    #choosepath {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn_journey').click(function () {
                alert("button click");
                $('#choosepath').css({"display":"normal"});
            });
        });
</script>
  </head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btn_journey">Start your journey</a>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4" id="choosepath">
    </div>
</body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was doing show / hide elements of a form according to whether an input element was empty or not, so that when hiding the elements the element following the hidden ones was repositioned occupying its space it was necessary to do a float: left of the element of such an element. Even using a plugin as dependsOn it was necessary to use float.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(#id/.class).show()
$(#id/.class).hide()
```

This one is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by button

`<button onclick"document.getElementById('elementid').style.display = 'none or block';">`

Comment: When adding an answer to a nine year old question with 13 existing answers where one of them is the accepted answer it is very important to include an explanation of how and why the answer works and also to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. The supplied code does not work as written and lacks an explanation showing how to customize it.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I have downvoted you, not because of the lack of explanation (which I agree with the others here) but because your answer will not work if someone gives the value of  "'none or block' ". Plus you have a syntax error in your code. (See, this is why an explanation helps.). Take the time to provide an answer so that it becomes useful to someone reading it.