# jQuery & CSS - Remove/Add display:none

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with this class :

```
.news{
  width:710px; 
  float:left;
  border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:none;
}
```

And I'd like with some jQuery methods remove that display:none; (so the div will showed) and than add it again (so the div will shadow).

How can I do it?

Comment: jQuery `$(".news").show()`? "so the div will shadow"...you mean it will fade out??

Comment: Yeah `$(".news").show()` works! The same `$(".news").hide()`!!! Thanks ;)

Comment: You can condense that down to one statement with `$('.news').toggle();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change css display none or block property using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery)

Answer (score 269, accepted):

To hide the `div`

```
$('.news').hide();
```

or

```
$('.news').css('display','none');
```

and to show the `div`:

```
$('.news').show();
```

or

```
$('.news').css('display','block');
```

Comment: $('.news').css('display','block'); worked for me! thanks Shehal!

Comment: How do I reset the 'display' style to whatever was set in CSS in the first place and not to 'block'?

Comment: Are these aliases?

Answer (score 82):

jQuery provides you with:

```
$(".news").hide();
$(".news").show();
```

You can then easily show and hide the element(s).

Comment: The problem is, `.show()` does nor remove `display: none`, but instead put `display: block` or `inline` depending on the element, and it can break the layout if the element use an unusual `display` style.

Comment: @lolesque I found a simple 'hack' to fix that issue. Simply use `element{display:none;}` in your css, but in your js, also use `element.hide()` at the same time. This will allow the `show()` function to work.

Answer (score 23):

In JavaScript:

```
getElementById("id").style.display = null;
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#id").css("display","");
```

Comment: I had to use $("#id").css('display', ''); to make it work properly in removing the inline style for "display"

Comment: Me too @TrippinBill (using Mac Firefox 43) - have submitted an edit. These seem to be the only way to *remove* the CSS property rather than reverse it. This allows it to be overridden by broader CSS assignments, whereas reversing it doesn't.

Answer (score 17):

So, let me give you sample code:

```
<div class="news">
Blah, blah, blah. I'm hidden.
</div>

<a class="trigger">Hide/Show News</a>
```

The link will be the trigger to show the div when clicked. So your Javascript will be:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $('.news').toggle();
});
```

You're almost always better off letting jQuery handle the styling for hiding and showing elements.

**Edit:** I see people above are recommending using `.show` and `.hide` for this. `.toggle` allows you to do both with just one effect. So that's cool.

Comment: Good idea to show the `toggle` function.  Many times if you need to click something and show it, you would like the functionality to hide it too.

Answer (score 12):

Use toggle to show and hide.

```
$('#mydiv').toggle()
```

### **Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jNqTa/**

Comment: Note that `.toggle()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @TylerH I can't see a note to see it's deprecated?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I was thinking of the toggle event http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 11):

The only way to remove an inline "display:none" via jQuery's css-api is by resetting it with the empty string (`null` does NOT work btw!!).

According to the jQuery docu this is the general way to "remove" a once set inline style property.

`$("#mydiv").css("display","");`

or

`$("#mydiv").css({display:""});`

should do the trick properly.

IMHO there is a method missing in jQuery that could be called "unhide" or "reveal" which instead of just setting another inline style property unsets the display value properly as described above. Or maybe `hide()` should store the initial inline value and `show()` should restore that...

Answer (score 10):

i'd suggest adding a class to display/hide elements:

```
.hide { display:none; }
```

and then use jquery's [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to show/hide the element:

```
$(".news").toggleClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not giving us much information but in general this might be a solution:

```
$("div.news").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Which other infos do you need? I think its a simple question, isn't it? Anyway, I resolved by using `$(".news").show()` and `$(".news").hide()` ;)

Comment: One obious question is: are there more div.news on the page. In which case this would display all of them.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery's .show() and .hide() functions are probably your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, toggle didn't work for me, and I received the error `uncaught type error toggle is not a function` when inspecting the element in browser. So I used the following code and it started working for me.

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    $('.news').attr('style', 'display:none');
})
```

Used jquery script file `jquery-2.1.3.min.js`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of elements you would like to `.hide()` or `.show()`, you are going to waste a lot of resources to do what you want - even if use `.hide(0)` or `.show(0)` - the 0 parameter is the duration of the animation.

As opposed to *Prototype.js* `.hide()` and `.show()` methods which only used to manipulate the display attribute of the element, *jQuery*'s implementation is more complex and not recommended for a large number of elements.

In this cases you should probably try `.css('display','none')` to hide and `.css('display','')` to show

`.css('display','block')` should be avoided, especially if you're working with inline elements, table rows (actually any table elements) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Considering lolesque's comment to best answer you can add either an attribute or a class to show/hide elements with display properties that differs from what it normally has, if your site needs backwards compatibility I would suggest making a class and adding/removing it to show/display the element

```
.news-show {
display:inline-block;
}

.news-hide {
display:none;
}
```

Replace inline-block with your preferred display method of your choice and use jquerys addclass https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ and removeclass https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ instead of show/hide, if backwards compatibility is no problem you can use attributes like this.

```
.news[data-news-visible=show] {
display:inline-block;
}

.news[data-news-visible=hide] {
display:none;
}
```

And use jquerys attr() http://api.jquery.com/attr/ to show and hide the element.

Whichever method you prefer it makes you able to easily implement css3 animations when showing/hiding elements this way

Answer (score 1):

Using `show()` adds `display:block` in place of `display:hide` which might break things.

To avoid that, you can have a class with property `display:none` and toggle that class for that element with `toggleClass()`.

```js
$("button").on('click', function(event){  $("div").toggleClass("hide"); });
```

```css
.hide{
   display:none;
}

div{
   width:40px;
   height:40px;
   background:#000;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>Toggle Box</button>
```

*None of the answers mentioned this.*

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different examples to show and hide using JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/vsLkb8a7/8/

CSS:

```
<style>
.elem{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;   
}

.divClass1{
    background:red;
}
.divClass2{
    background:blue;
}
.divClass3{
    background:green;
}
.divClass4{
    background:orange;
}
.divClass5{
    background:black;
}
.divClass6{
    background:yellow;
}
.hidemeClass{
  display:none;
}

.showmeClass{
  display:block;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<button class="myBtn">show and hide div</button>
<div id="" class="elem divClass1"></div>
<div id="" class="elem divClass2 showmeClass"></div>
<div id="divId" class="elem divClass3"></div>
<div id="" class="elem divClass4"></div>
<div id="" class="elem divClass5"></div>
<div id="" class="elem divClass6"></div>
```

jS:

```
jQuery(".myBtn").click(function () {

  //Simple toggle
  jQuery('.divClass1').toggle();
  

  //OR use a toggle between classes. Of course you would have to add: .hidemeClass{display:none;}.showmeClass{display:block;} to your stylesheet and the element should have atleast the default class.
  jQuery('.divClass2').toggleClass('hidemeClass showmeClass');



  //OR let's use a toggle with a case statement
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('hidediv');
  
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('hidediv')){


    //using Plain Javascript
    const el= document.getElementById("divId");
    el.style = "display:none;"; //display:unset or :initial


    //or using Attr()
    jQuery('.divClass4').attr('style', 'display:none');
    //display:unset or :initial

    //or using css()
    jQuery('.divClass5').css('display','none');
    //display:unset or :initial


    //or using builtin hide()
    jQuery('.divClass6').hide();

  }else{

    //using Plain Javascript
    const el= document.getElementById("divId");
    el.style = "display:block;"; //display:unset or :initial

    //or using Attr()
    jQuery('.divClass4').attr('style', 'display:block'); 
    //display:unset or :initial

    //or using css()
    jQuery('.divClass5').css('display','block');
    //display:unset or :initial


    //or using builtin show()
    jQuery('.divClass6').show();

  }


});
```