# ways to hide/show a div with a toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm looking into implementing something similar to the li's in [chrome extension page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en).
Should i use [jQuery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)? maybe someone can provide some sort of a sample
code i could start off with? (i'm new to jQuery)

Comment: Please edit you question to make it more understandable

Comment: Tom look at my answer to see how to mimic that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any complicated plugins, you can do all of this with jquery. Here is a quick sample i whipped out. It's simple really.

The html

```
<div id="outer"> 
    <p>Some outer content </p>
   <div id="inner">Slider Content </div> 
</div> ​
```

The css

```
#outer{
   height: 200px; 
   width: 200px; 
   background-color: brown; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   position: relative;     
}
#inner{ 
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;     
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%; 
}
```

The JS

```
  $('#outer').hover(
    function(){
       $('#inner').animate({ top: '0%' }, 'easein' );  
    }, 
    function(){
       $('#inner').animate({ top: '100%' }, 'easein' );  
    }        
   ); ​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/ZtAj2/3/) it is in action.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [jQuery & CSS - Remove/Add display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059596/jquery-css-remove-add-displaynone)

I think that it should work for hiding/showing.

Answer (score 0):

Its extremely hard to answer your question. But showing and hiding a div is very easy, just use `.toggle()`

```
$("#mydiv").toggle();
```

Comment: but see how the div's are sliding upwards

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jquery UI Accordion rather than inventing your own wheel. These link might help  you.

> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion
>
> http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/?p=1.1.2

Comment: No need for plugins, jquery will suffice. Look at my post.

Comment: When I do need something I do little bit of googling first. I don't waste my time creating my own plugins when there are a lot of good plugins that has sophisticated features & BTW using plugins is not hard and complicated than writing your own code to mimic it.

Comment: It's not complicated, it's rather easy. Complicated for someone who can't code, in that case, go ahead and include thousands of lines of code you don't really need. Your choice. Btw that plugin doesn't even really do what this post wants it to do. I'm not against plugins, just against the idea of not being able to think for yourself and realizing when something is simple and doesn't reaquire a bloated plugin. I did it in 8 lines, how many lines of code does that plugin you suggested have in it ?