# Button click makes content appear in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

At the top of my view /Home/Clear.cshtml, I have

```
<button type="button" id="show" class="find-proj">Find Project</button>
```

At the bottom of my /Shared/_Layout.cshtml view, I have a table that is wrapped in

```
<div class="wrapper">...</div>
```

My CSS has

```
.wrapper { display: none; }
```

And in the head of my /Shared/_Layout.cshtml view I have the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".wrapper").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

The goal is that when I press the button, the table appears at the bottom of the page. The table is currently invisible, but when I press the button, nothing happens.
**EDIT:** The mistake was that for some reason jQuery was being loaded at the bottom of the page for some strange reason. I changed `$(".wrapper").show();` to `$(".wrapper").css('display','block');` and moved jQuery to load before it, and it works like a charm. Thanks everyone!

Comment: is the javascript event triggering?

Comment: I just put your code into a snippet and it works as expected.  Did you forget to include jquery?  Any errors in the browser console?  Is the rendered HTML in your browser appearing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can  try with the following way.

```
$('.wrapper').css('display','block');
```

And also kindly take a look at the comment of the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059661/3397630

Hope it was helpful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks
Thanks

karthik

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there aren't any JS errors, and the `$("#show")` selector returns a result, as well as the `$(".wrapper")` selector.  That might be the issue; however, it could also be the `show()` call isn't overriding the wrapper `display:none` definition.  A way to work around that is:

1) Add a class to the DIV:

```
<div class="find-project wrapper">...</div>
```

2) And then change the button click handler to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".find-project").removeClass("wrapper");
  });
});
</script>
```

Later you can then hide it again by adding the class back via:

```
$(".find-project").addClass("wrapper");
```

Since the wrapper class defines `display: none`, calling `show()` seems to not be overriding that, having one class to identify the element and one class to show/hide it is the perfect combo in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

.show() set the style attribute, where the display:none exists in the .wrapper class.  These tend to conflict.  Use one or the other.  I find it easier to have a .hidden{display:none;} class and  toggle between .addClass('hidden') and .removeClass('hidden'), or $('.wrapper').toggleClass('hidden')