# How to toggle css visibility with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a FAQ page much like the one here: https://www.harrys.com/help
I want to create the effect where clicking a question will display an answer.

My code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/8UVAf/1/

Can anybody tell me why my javascript is not working? I realized I combined jQuery and Javascript, but I read somewhere that it should compile fine.

HTML:

```
<div class="questions-answer-block">
    <p class="question">This is a Question?</p>
    <p id="answer" class="hideinit">Here is the Answer</p>
</div>
<div class="questions-answer-block">
    <p class="question">This is a Question?</p>
    <p id="answer" class="hideinit">Here is the Answerdadawdawdawdawdawdawdawdwadawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawdawd</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".question").click(function (argument) {
    if(document.getElementById("answer").className.match(/(?:^|\s)hideinit(?!\S)/)) {
        document.getElementByID("answer").className = "display";
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a fundamental mis-understanding of `id` and `class` parameters. `id` values **must** be unique, classes can be shared.

Comment: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery/9528667#9528667

Comment: ^thanks. That worked! @esqew I see now that having ID's as the identified for all "answers" does not work. If I change all answers to share the "answer" class, how should I use the getElementById function. Is there a class alternative?

Comment: jQuery's ***much easier version of*** `getElementById`  is `$('#elementID')`, and to get by class name `$('.class-name')`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @robinhuang The vanilla Javascript version would be `document.getElementsByClassnName()`

Comment: [document.getElementsByClassName()](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom08.htm).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! This is has been really helpful. I'm sorry if I asked a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your Javascript could be shortened to:

```
$(".question").click(function(argument) {  
    $(this).parent().find(".answer").removeClass("hideinit").addClass("display");
});
```

In order to make this work the only other thing you need to do is to make `question` a class rather than as an id. That looks like:

```
<p class="answer hideinit">the answer</p>
```

**[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9r3/2/)**

---

**Edit: Add Hide / Show**

To get this to hide and show as expected you'll want to update the code to check the current class before hiding and showing. That looks like:

```
$(".question").click(function(argument) {  
    var el = $(this).parent().find(".answer");
    if (el.hasClass("display")) {
       el.removeClass("display").addClass("hideinit");
    } else {
        el.removeClass("hideinit").addClass("display");
    }
});
```

**[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9r3/3/)**

Comment: This works! But, how can I edit the jQuery so that the answer will disappear after you click on Question again? I'd rather not use the toggle function because I want to directly control other css properties as well.

Comment: Just add an if "has class" and do a remove class. (Example on its way)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, in your JSFiddle you were not including the jQuery library. I've adjusted your code, I think this is what you were going for:

```
$(".question").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

## Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UVAf/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Please watch your includes in your JSFiddle as the version you linked was not including the jQuery library. You should also clean up your multiple `id` references (as this is invalid HTML and will cause some issues down the road).

Those issues aside, you can use jQuery's [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to help you with this particular problem:

```
$(".question").click(function (argument) {
    $(this).next(".hideinit").removeClass("hideinit").addClass("display");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UVAf/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".question").on('click',function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```