# How to hide elements after button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, razor, jquery-events, submit-button

I am unable to hide a list on button click on partial view.
This is what I am trying to do, but the following code does nothing.
Can anyone please help me with this?

```
<script>       
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#resultBtn').onclick(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#List').hide();
            commit();
        })
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might need a JSFiddle, the script seems to be good, but I guess the problem comes from your HTML5 code actually.
Anyway, here are some advice that might help.

`#resultBtn` is written in camelCase, so `#List` should be `#list`. Plus, if you have a problem, try to `console.log('something')` in the click callback function to see if something happen.

Oh,  **I finally spotted the problem**, you should easily find it if you open the console of your browser. **You can not do `onclick()` on a jQuery element, it's only `click`.** A good habit could be to use *edit* **`on()`** *(or `bind()`)*, you might find it useful someday.

```
$(function() {
    $('#resultBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#list').hide();
        commit();
    });
});
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: as of jquery 1.7, bind has been deprecated, you should use on, see: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I did as you suggested, but the table hides only for a couple of seconds, and as soon as the page loads on submission the list is displayed back again.

Comment: @ZebRawnsley yes thank you. Are you sure it's deprecated, I still use use because sometimes I find unbind() useful.

Comment: @SamViq of course, every time the page loads, the state will be reset. Basically, you can't save JS state between two pages. What you can do is use a bit a back-end code (I you post some data for instance) or maybe you can get some get parameters in the URL to know wether or not the list should be displayed.

Comment: @Cohars it still works but could be removed at any point you decide to update your jQuery reference, the new preferred version of unbind() is off()

Comment: @SamViq Don't forget to check an answer as we think at least one of us gave the good answer to your question :)

Comment: @Cohars None of the answers worked because all the values are being reset once the page is submitted. I tried to work it on the controller side, by retaining the results but i encountered another problem. Seems like i have to work with PostBack. Thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @SamViq So you should change the question. Because I assure you that we answered it. that's a front-end JS question. Of course everything is reset one the page is submitted, this is static. Nothing is saved.

Comment: @Cohars i might post a new one if i need to. But i think it would be good to keep this question as it might help others.

Comment: Yes, sure :) But be careful to be clear in the question. What you want is not to hide a button when the user clicks on it, because you know how to do. What you should ask for is how to save data and use them in the front-end, to know wether or not you should show/hide a button.

Answer (score 0):

Make the element invisible, but treat it as if it is still there:

```
document.getElementById("resultBtn").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("List").style.visibility = "hidden";
return false;
}
```

Hide the element and treat it as if it is non-existent:

```
document.getElementById("resultBtn").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("List").style.display = "none";
return false;
}
```

Comment: There is also `document.getElementById("List").hidden = true;` in modern browsers at least. :-)

Comment: @RobG I think he want's to use jQuery I wouldn't recommend it neither but it might be useful to keep it simple if he want's to solve the problems he mentioned in the comments. Anyway, you forgot the `return false`. Please don't down-vote the good answers just to get yours in the top.

Comment: @Cohars—not my down vote, not my answer. I was just suggesting another way to hide the element for **this** answer.

Comment: I never downvoted any of the other answers... not that I'd know what I'm doing since I know very little jQuery at all. I will add return false as well. (you're right, I forgot that part)

Answer (score -1):

You can set display property to none to hide the element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#resultBtn').onclick(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#List').css('display','none'); //<--- like here
                commit();
            })
          });
```

Comment: @SamViq - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery

Comment: This is an alternate way to achieve what you are trying to do. What exactly happens when you set display property to none?

Comment: @Ishita the list hides onclick but is displayed back once the page is submitted.

Comment: aah.. well.. i can see Cohor has answered your question. But, make sure to be more clear and include all the details when you ask the question :)