# Is there a way to change Style via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

There's an error message that I want to hide on some scenarios:

```
<div id="PickerPopupNoResultsMessage" style="color:red; font-weight: bold; " class="ui-helper-hidden">
    Please select Name first.
</div>
```

It renders when I do this in the view:

```
 $('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');
```

so it becomes

```
<div id="PickerPopupNoResultsMessage" class="" style="color: red; font-weight: bold; display: none;">
    Please select Name first.
</div>
```

I am unable to remove `display: none`. I also tried `removeClass` and `addClass`. In `addClass` I am setting `display: block` and all it does is add the class, but `display: none` still stays.

Please help as this small thing has taken a lot of my time :(

Comment: try display:inline or display:block according to your need

Comment: I already tried that , that's why i asked here.. seriously you'd downvote some just like that

Comment: FYI i didn't down vote. you may try $('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').css() to change css

Answer (score 1):

Changing a class won't affect in-line styles on the element itself.  For that you'd likely need to directly [edit its CSS properties](http://api.jquery.com/css/).  Something like this:

```
$('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try any one of these:

```
$('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').css('display', 'block');
```

Or if you want to store state of display property in jquery data cache try This:

```
$('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').show();
```

Make sure you do it when it's available in the `DOM`. To do it after the element is loaded in the `DOM` you may try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').show();

    // Or This

    $('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Any of those will work. You may use `inline`, `inline-block` or `block` when using `css` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery css() function:

```
$('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').css('display','block;')
```

Or show():

```
$('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').show()
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/hxjnzxtu/)
You can read more about css() at the  [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) 
Or, more in depth answers can be found at this SO question:
[How to change css display none or block property using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the html/styling.

Currently you have..

```
<div id="PickerPopupNoResultsMessage" style="color:red; font-weight: bold; " class="ui-helper-hidden">
Please select Name first.
</div>
```

Loose the class and adjust your style to..

```
<div id="PickerPopupNoResultsMessage" style="color:red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" >
Please select Name first.
</div>
```

Then your jQuery can be adjusted to..

```
$('#PickerPopupNoResultsMessage').css( "display", "block" )
```