# JQuery.css("display") = "block" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I wanted to show and hide my `TextBox` based on value selected in `RadiobuttonList`. I wrote the following code for that

```
$("#<%= rbtnIsPFEnabled.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                pfno = $("#<%= txtPFNo.ClientID %>");
                if ($("#<%= rbtnIsPFEnabled.ClientID %> input:checked").val() == "Yes") {
                    pfno.css("dispay") = "block";
                }
                else
                    pfno.css("dispay") = "none";
            });
```

Though I had achieved my task by using `JQuery.show()` and  `JQuery.hide()` but was not satisfied as I wanted to know why first approach failed. Second is I used `$("#<%= rbtnIsPFEnabled.ClientID %>")` in above code, can I reduce it to one by using something else second time like `this` or anything else?

I tried `$(this+" input:checked").val()` and `$(this.toString()+" input:checked").val()` but it did not work, so I had to repeat it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");
$("#id").css("display", "block");
```

if Your `pfno` contains your ID

then this should work

```
$(pfno).css("display", "none");
$(pfno).css("display", "block");
```

**You Should Use FireBug For Debugging**

**EDIT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun(obj) {

        if ($("#<%= rbtnIsPFEnabled.ClientID %> input:checked").val()=='Yes') {
            $("#<%= txtPFNo.ClientID %>").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $("#<%= txtPFNo.ClientID %>").css("display", "none");
        }
    }


</script>  

<asp:RadioButtonList   ID="rbtnIsPFEnabled"     runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" onchange="fun(this);"> </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" onchange="fun(this);"> </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPFNo"/>
```

Comment: You read the full question? `"also tried second solution by replacing pfno.css("dispay") = "block" to pfno.css("dispay","block") but both could not work"`

Comment: no - pfno would not be written like that ,  you would just do pfno.css()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery

Comment: @4dgaurav - good catch , I can't believe someone needed to copy another answer to explain how to set a css property with jquery

Comment: Its an alternative solution, and do not address my second question. So, +1, but not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue in multiple way using `jQuery`.
e.g.

```
$(pfno).css("display", "none"); //used when you are defining single css property or in chaining method
$(pfno).css({"display":"none"}); // used when you are defining multiple CSS property           
$(pfno).hide(); //show/hide function also perform display block/none functionality which is mostly used in script
```

Answer (score -1):

ok  first of all this is not correct :

```
     pfno.css("dispay") = "block";
```

above will never work

`pfno.css({ 'display' : 'block' });` is how you set a css property ,

`pfno.css( 'display' , 'block' );`  is another way to set a css property , so that measn yuo are doing something else wrong..  you need to set an alert or write to the console to confirm that your if statement and your click handler are working

Comment: I want to get selected value and not checking anything like your code.

Comment: oohh... I see..  you are using radio buttons , and checking the value of the one that is checked.... sorry about that