# Why isn't my html/js code working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with different panels, and a function that uses jQuery to show/hide them. I've debugged it for hours, but still can't figure out what's wrong.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function toTab(curtab,tname){
console.log('toTab: '+curtab+', '+tname);
$('div.panel#'+curtab).attr('hidden','hidden');
$('div.panel#'+tname).removeAttr('hidden');
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class='panel' id='main'>
<div id='rafosd'><h1 id='rafos'>
    RafOS<em class='flashing'>_</em>
    </h1></div>
    <a id='mainl' class='panelchange' href='javascript:toTab("main","signin");'><!-- !!! JS FUNCTION CALLED HERE! !!! !-->Sign in</a>
    <script>
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.flashing').toggleClass('hide');
        }, 500);
    </script>
</div>
<!-- !-->
<div class='panel' hidden id='signin'>
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
<form id='fsignin' style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" method='post' action='api/signin.php'>
<h1>Sign in</h1>
<h3 style="color: rgba(165, 165, 165, 1)">&mdash; Control your games remotely &mdash;</h3>
<input type='text' class='input' required placeholder='Username' autocomplete='off' name='username' id='signin-username'>
<br>
<input type='password' class='input' required placeholder='Password' name='password' autocomplete='off' id='signin-password'>
<br>
<input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' id='signin-submit' value='SIGN IN'><br>
Don&apos;t have an account? <strong><a id='signin' class='panelchange' href='javascript:toTab("signin","signup");'><!-- !!! JS FUNCTION CALLED HERE! !!! !-->Sign up</a></strong>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- !-->
<div class='panel' hidden id='signup'>
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
<form id='fsignup' style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" method='post' action='api/signup.php'>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<h3 style="color: rgba(165, 165, 165, 1)">&mdash; Control your games remotely &mdash;</h3>
<input type='text' class='input' placeholder='Username' autocomplete='off' name='username' id='signup-username'>
<br>
<input type='password' class='input' placeholder='Password' name='password' autocomplete='off' id='signup-password'>
<br>
<input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' id='signup-submit' value='SIGN UP'><br>
Already have an account? <strong><a id='signup' class='panelchange' href='javascript:toTab("signup","signin");'><!-- !!! JS FUNCTION CALLED HERE! !!! !-->Sign in</a></strong>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### NOTE:

If this is too much code and you can't understand it very well, or would like to see only a part/all of the code, the page is live [here](http://www.rsoindustries.com/RafOS).

Comment if you don't understand something, and I'll do my best to explain.

---

## EDIT:

Working fine now, thanks to [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5154205/sean) and [slightlynybbled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037766/slightlynybbled)

Comment: What is not working?  Also where is your javascript at in relation to the html?  And what does your console.log print out?

Comment: What is `attr('hidden')` supposed to do? Should provide explanation of what you expect this code to do

Comment: I think you want to try modifying the display attribute for the div panel instead of the hidden attribute. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery

Comment: It always seems to help me to place all javascript into '.js' files and use the 'document ready' functionality of jQuery.  You can see the 'document ready' functionality http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: @Taplar Just commented where the function is called, scroll right. Also fixed ID's

Comment: @Sean I've tried doing that, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The screen just turns white. What should happen?

Comment: your '.signin' element is a nested child of the outer '#main'.  Main has opacity of 0 and signin has opacity of 1.  Also hidden is not being removed from the signin element

Comment: You have two functions called toTab, both of which are included, one in-line and one in main.js, one modifies opacity, the other tinkers with the hidden attribute, are you sure you don't want to combine those, they are likely conflicting.

Comment: @slightlynybbled Putting it in a js file actually made it work somehow. Thanks! Do you mind putting that in an answer so I mark it as accepted, and other people aren't bothered to come here and after reading the whole thing it's already been answered?

Comment: @Sean Oh, that was probably it, just saw your comment, sorry... By editing main.js, I removed that old function...

Comment: @RafDev, so which do you consider your answer? mine or @slightlynybbled? :)

Comment: @Sean Yours, his only made me realize yours was right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two functions called toTab, both of which are included. 
One is in-line:

```
function toTab(curtab,tname){
console.log('toTab: '+curtab+', '+tname);
$('div.panel#'+curtab).attr('hidden','hidden');
$('div.panel#'+tname).removeAttr('hidden');
};
```

and one in main.js:

```
function toTab(curtab,tname){
$('div.panel#'+curtab).animate({
   opacity: 0,
})
$('div.panel#'+tname).animate({
   opacity: 1,
})
}
```

The latter modifies opacity, the former tinkers with the hidden attribute, are you sure you don't want to combine those, they are likely conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are incorrect. You need to have space between the class `panel` and id.

This

```
$('div.panel#'+curtab).attr('hidden','hidden');
$('div.panel#'+tname).removeAttr('hidden');
```

needs to be

```
$('div.panel #'+curtab).attr('hidden','hidden');
$('div.panel #'+tname).removeAttr('hidden');
```