# HTML / JQUERY Paragraph visible / hide

Tags: jquery, html

I have this paragraph that I want it to make it visible

```
 <p class="decriptioncontent"  id="EN_descriptionText" style="display:none;">
Alarma entre los barones: «Sánchez ya está en campaña»
</p>
```

with this JQUERY function

```
$( languageCode + "_descriptionText" ).css( "display", "visible" );
```

but it does not work !

I've tried also with

```
$( languageCode + "_descriptionText" ).css( "display", "block" );
```

Comment: `visible` isn't a valid `display` type, try `block` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change css display none or block property using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `#` before id selector and use **[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** method to make it visible.

```
$('#' + languageCode + "_descriptionText" ).show(); 
//-^-------
```

---

Or  by updating css `display` property.

```
$('#' + languageCode + "_descriptionText" ).css( "display", "block" );
//-^-------
```

---

```js
var languageCode = 'EN';
$('#' + languageCode + "_descriptionText").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="decriptioncontent" id="EN_descriptionText" style="display:none;">
  Alarma entre los barones: «Sánchez ya está en campaña»
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( '#' + languageCode + "_descriptionText" ).css( "display", "block" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
$('#' + languageCode + "_descriptionText" ).show();
```