# How to change rendered="false"> rendered="true" on JSF PAGE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

i'm developing a spring project. i'm using jsf java javascript and jquery.

but i have on problem.

t
if user check checkbox

How can i this.

i tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ozgur() {
        if(document.getElementById('fikirCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById("secondPage").setAttribute("rendered",true);

        }else{
            document.getElementById("secondPage").setAttribute("rendered",false);
        }


    };
</script>
```

checkbox boolean check box.

Thank you for help

Comment: Did you checked the answers?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

You just cant! The `rendered` attribute is evaluated at server side by JSF. Thus, when it process the page, it evaluates the component and if the result of `rendered` is false, the component doest not get processed and does not go to the final html to the client.

**Solution:**

You can wrap your component to a div and use `style: display:none` and control it with javascript. Take a look at [How to change css display none or block property using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery). That can help you out.

Comment: You can put the `style: display=none` on the component itself to. No need to wrap it (in this usecase)

Answer (score 0):

Either you can give rendered flag value directly like

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBean.value}" id="chk" rendered="true"/>
```

or from Bean

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBean.value}" id="chk" rendered="#{myBean.isRender}"/>
```