# How the set property of a div stored in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some string stored in a JavaScript variable e.g.

```
var content= '<div id="report" style="display: none;">some content....</div>';
```

How to set property of this div to display: block; using jQuery?

Comment: if you just want to change value of display use this command *content.replace('none','block')* but if you want to write it in better way follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-to-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery

Comment: This is not "*a div stored in a JavaScript variable*"! This is a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with jQuery's [**`.parseHTML()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) and [**`.css()`**](https://api.jquery.com/css/):

```js
var content= '<div id="report" style="display: none;">some content....</div>';
content = $($.parseHTML(content)).css('display', 'block');
console.log(content[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```