# Jquery show/hide element (button) when another element has a value/text - WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to write a function to show/hide Add to cart button (WooCommerce) when the price of product is zero - 0,00 €. When the page loads and the product has this zero price it should hide the product Add to cart button and when I chose an option and the price change, for example to 30,00 €, then it should show the button. In console.log() I see the prices change but the condition to show/hide the button doesn't work.

```
var zeroVal = "0,00 €",
    newVal = jQuery('.price').text();
jQuery('.price').change(function(){
    if(newVal == zeroVal) {
     jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').attr("style","display: none!important");
   } else {
     jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').attr("style","display: block!important");
   }
});

function priceChangeListener() {
   if(newVal != zeroVal) {
     newVal = jQuery('.price').text();   
   }
   jQuery('.price').change();
};
setInterval(priceChangeListener, 500);
```

What do I do wrong? Is there any simpler solution? I was not able to find any. Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Move `newVal = jQuery('.price').text();` into your `change` event handler

Comment: what do you see in the console log when you log both price at each interval?

Comment: @RyanWilson this I tried, now I get in console log (index):774 Uncaught ReferenceError: newVal is not defined

Comment: @Arif in the console log I see the price changes as I select the options, however the condition doesn't take an effect

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the problem might be caused by your implementation of the `.attr()` method.

According to the [jQuery API Docs,](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set a simple attribute, the first argument to the `.attr()` method should be the name of the attribute and the second should be the desired value.

Ex. `$( "#greatphoto" ).attr( "alt", "Beijing Brush Seller" );`

To set multiple attributes at once, an object should be passed in containing key-value pairs, the keys being the name of the attribute and the value being the value.

Ex. `$( "#greatphoto" ).attr({ alt: "Beijing Brush Seller", title: "photo by Kelly Clark" });`

Additionally, [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582619/how-can-i-change-css-display-none-or-block-property-using-jquery) provides alternative methods of showing/hiding elements that might be useful. Namely, the `.hide()` and `.show(`) methods, along with the `.css()` jQuery method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think so, it looks like the condition if/else doesn't take an effect at all